# Start second while loop only after first is finished

Tags: lua

I'm trying to write a function that puts the remaining seconds into a human readable format.  The problem I'm having(I think) is that my second while loop is trying to do it's job before the first is finished.  I'll end up with "1 hour, 271 minutes and 37 seconds. In my latest attempt, I tried to use minNeeded but that doesn't work either because it's checking for it's existence prior to the first loop being finished. How can I manage this?

```
function prettyTime(secs)

    local hr = 0
    local hrDisplay = ''
    local min = 0
    local minDislplay = ''
    local minNeeded = 0

    if(secs >= 3600) then
        while secs >= 3600 do
            secs = secs - 3600
            hr = hr + 1
            if secs < 3600 then
                secsRemaining = secs
                minNeeded = 1
            end
        end
    else
        minNeeded = 1
    end
    while true do
        if(minNeeded == 1){
            while secsRemaining >= 60 do
                secsRemaining = secsRemaining - 60
                min = min + 1
            end
        end
    end

    if hr > 1 then
        hrDisplay = hr .. ' hours, '
    elseif hr == 1 then
        hrDisplay = '1 hour, '
    end
    if min > 1 then
        minDisplay = min .. ' minutes and '
    elseif min == 1 then
        minDisplay = '1 minute and '
    else
        minDisplay = ''
    end

    return hrDisplay .. minDisplay .. secs .. ' seconds'

end
```

Comment: Your function has a `while true` without any kind of `break`, so the function can't actually return. Also, inside that loop, the `if` statement gives a syntax error.

Comment: To be honest, you don't really need any loops for this. You can just use `%` and `//` to calculate hours, minutes, and seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Code has few bugs, `if(minNeeded == 1){` is syntax error, `while true do` will never break.
Here is the simple converter,

```
function prettyTime(sec)
  local sec = tonumber(sec)
  if sec <= 0 then
    return "00.00.00";
  else
    h = tonumber(string.format("%02.f", math.floor(sec/3600)))
    m = tonumber(string.format("%02.f", math.floor(sec/60 - (h*60))))
    s = tonumber(string.format("%02.f", math.floor(sec - h*3600 - m*60)))
    -- return h.."."..m.."."..s
  end

    local res = ''
    if h == 1 then
        res = res ..h .. ' hour, '
    elseif h > 1 then
        res = res ..h .. ' hours, '
    end

    if m <= 1 then
        res = res ..m .. ' minute, '
    elseif m > 1 then
        res = res ..m .. ' minute, '
    end

    if s <= 1 then
        res = res ..s .. ' second, '
    elseif s > 1 then
        res = res ..s .. ' seconds '
    end
  return res
end

print(prettyTime(3670)) -- 1 hour, 1 minute, 10 seconds
```